# Extracting XML data from CLOB

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

How can I extract Food ItemID and Food Item Name and Quantity from the data as mentioned below. This is in clob column in plsql.

```
<ServiceDetails>
    <FoodItemDetails>
        <FoodItem FoodItemID="6486" FoodItemName="CARROT" Quantity="2" Comments="" ServingQuantityID="142" ServingQuantityName="SMALL GLASS" FoodItemPrice="50" ItemDishPriceID="5336" CurrencyName="INR" Currency Id="43"/>
    </FoodItemDetails>
    <BillOption>
        <Bill Details Total Price="22222" BillOption="cash"/>
    </BillOption>
    <Authoritativeness/>
</Service Details>
```

Comment: please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract xml value from Clob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675525/extract-xml-value-from-clob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [xmltable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#SQLRF06232).

Data setup:

```
create table myt(
col1 clob
);

insert into myt values('<ServiceDetails>
    <FoodItemDetails>
        <FoodItem FoodItemID="6486" FoodItemName="CARROT" Quantity="2" Comments="" ServingQuantityID="142" ServingQuantityName="SMALL GLASS" FoodItemPrice="50" ItemDishPriceID="5336" CurrencyName="INR" CurrencyId="43"/>
    </FoodItemDetails>
    <BillOption>
        <BillDetails TotalPrice="22222" BillOption="cash"/>
    </BillOption>
    <Authoritativeness/>
</ServiceDetails>'
);

commit;
```

Query:

```
select cols.*
from myt
cross join xmltable('ServiceDetails/FoodItemDetails/FoodItem' passing xmltype(col1)
            columns fooditemid varchar2(10) path '@FoodItemID',
                fooditemname varchar2(20) path '@FoodItemName'
        ) cols;
```

Result:

```
FOODITEMID FOODITEMNAME
---------- --------------------
6486       CARROT
```

Comment: AND HOW CAN I USE INNER JOIN WITH  ANOTHER TABLE THAT IS HAVING FOODITEMID IS PRIMARY KEY.@Eat Å Peach

Comment: Use it as inline view or CTE. example: `select * from (<above query>) a inner join other_table b on b.fooditemid = a.fooditemid;`